# Load Balanced IP OVH and Play static files

Tags: ssl, playframework, routes, openssl, playframework-2.0

I am using OVH to host my website and I use IP Load Balancing so my configuration look like this:

443 (Load Balanced IP) ----------> 80 (Server)

80 (Load Balanced IP) ----------> 80 (Server)

Unfortunately since I do not use https on the play project all static files urls are http:// thus my certificate is not shown green.

Is there a way to enforce play to rewrite all URLs using `https` instead of `http://`?

I use the java version of Play.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, the load balancer is now upgraded and you have more control over it.

However, sending from 443 to 80 is a bad idea and it will never work properly, you must setup 443 -> 443 and 80 -> 80.